# Consulta SQL filtro Avanzado con Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql

tengo este modelo de base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero realizar una consulta que me cumpla las siguientes condiciones.

1. se deben listar todos los estudiantes
2. quiero poder ver el tipo de caracterización solamente de la caracterización con el semestre de mayor orden
3. no deben repetirse los estudiantes

ya he intentado de distintas maneras pero siempre me salen todas las caracterizaciones que tiene el estudiante y quiero que se vea solamente el tipo de la caracterización con el semestre de mayor orden por cada estudiante

ejemplo:

Yo estoy haciendo esta consulta

```
select e.nombre, c.id, s.nombre as "semestre", s.orden, t.nombre as "tipo" 
from estudiante e, caracterizacion c, tipo t, semestre s 
where e.id=c.estudiante_id and t.id=c.tipo_id and s.id=c.semestre_id
```

y me esta dando como resultado lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo quiero que solamente me salgan los siguiente resultados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los que están encerrados en rojo son los que quiero que me den como resultado y corresponden al semestre de mayor orden de las caracterizaciones de cada estudiante.

Espero me puedan ayudar, anexo código para generación de las base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE "Estudiantes" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "nombre" varchar NOT NULL,
    "tipo_documento" varchar NOT NULL,
    "documento" varchar NOT NULL,
    "celular" varchar NOT NULL,
    "telefono" varchar NOT NULL,
    "genero" integer NOT NULL,
    "fecha_nac" varchar NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar NOT NULL,
    "direccion" varchar NOT NULL,
    "foto" BINARY NOT NULL,
    "programa" integer NOT NULL,
    "Estado" integer NOT NULL,
    "Created" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Estudiantes_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Programas" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "nombre" varchar NOT NULL,
    "duracion_semestres" integer NOT NULL,
    "snies" varchar NOT NULL,
    "Franja" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Programas_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Semestres" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "semestre" varchar NOT NULL,
    "orden" integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Semestres_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Caracterizaciones" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "estudiante" integer NOT NULL,
    "descripcion" varchar NOT NULL,
    "semestre" integer NOT NULL,
    "Nivelado" integer NOT NULL,
    "tipo" integer NOT NULL,
    "usuario" integer NOT NULL,
    "Created " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Caracterizaciones_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Tipos_caracterizaciones" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "nombre" serial NOT NULL,
    "default" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Tipos_caracterizaciones_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Users" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "user_name" varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "nombre" varchar NOT NULL,
    "apellido" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar NOT NULL,
    "grupo" integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Users_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Grupos" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "nombre" varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Grupos_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE "Genero" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "nombre" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Genero_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);



ALTER TABLE "Estudiantes" ADD CONSTRAINT "Estudiantes_fk0" FOREIGN KEY ("genero") REFERENCES "Genero"("id");
ALTER TABLE "Estudiantes" ADD CONSTRAINT "Estudiantes_fk1" FOREIGN KEY ("programa") REFERENCES "Programas"("id");



ALTER TABLE "Caracterizaciones" ADD CONSTRAINT "Caracterizaciones_fk0" FOREIGN KEY ("estudiante") REFERENCES "Estudiantes"("id");
ALTER TABLE "Caracterizaciones" ADD CONSTRAINT "Caracterizaciones_fk1" FOREIGN KEY ("semestre") REFERENCES "Semestres"("id");
ALTER TABLE "Caracterizaciones" ADD CONSTRAINT "Caracterizaciones_fk2" FOREIGN KEY ("tipo") REFERENCES "Tipos_caracterizaciones"("id");
ALTER TABLE "Caracterizaciones" ADD CONSTRAINT "Caracterizaciones_fk3" FOREIGN KEY ("usuario") REFERENCES "Users"("id");


ALTER TABLE "Users" ADD CONSTRAINT "Users_fk0" FOREIGN KEY ("grupo") REFERENCES "Grupos"("id");
```

Comment: al utilizar una función de agregación como `MAX()` no te convendría al final utilizar algo como `GROUP BY nombre` ? considerando que mas de un registro tiene el mismo nombre es decir Cesar?

Comment: @shadow realmente esta ultima linea `and s.id= (select max(id) from semestre where id=c.semestre_id)` no altera en nada la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por una cuestión de orden yo te recomendaría usar `JOIN` explícitos:

```
SELECT 
    e.nombre, 
    c.id, 
    s.nombre AS semestre, 
    s.orden, 
    t.nombre AS tipo
FROM estudiante e, 
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id 
JOIN tipo t ON t.id = c.tipo_id
JOIN semestre s ON s.id = c.semestre_id
```

Segundo, tus tablas tienen nombre en plural y tu ejemplo en singular. Vamos a obviar este aspecto.

Según yo veo, tu problema es que `caracterizacion` es una tabla puente entre los estudiantes y los semestres, al estilo

```
estudiante_id | semestre_id
---------------------------
      1       |     1
      1       |     2
      1       |     3
      2       |     1
      2       |     2
      2       |     3
      3       |     1
      3       |     2
      3       |     3
```

Pienso que puedes tener el mismo problema con la entidad `tipo` que todavía no has notado. Si en cada registro de `caracterización` puede aparecer cualquier `estudiante` combinado con cualquier `semestre` y cualquier `tipo` entonces se va a repetir el problema. Como sea, **simplifiquemos el problema**. Digamos que se deja afuera `tipo` y el problema se reduce a:

```
SELECT 
    e.nombre, 
    c.id, 
    s.nombre AS semestre, 
    s.orden
FROM estudiante e, 
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id 
JOIN semestre s ON s.id = c.semestre_id
```

Pienso que para hacer lo que buscas hay cuatro caminos.

## El camino horrible (no lo hagan por favor)

Puedes hacer que en cada fila el orden sea el máximo posible dado que para esa fila sabes el id del estudiante:

```
SELECT
    e.nombre,
    c.id,
    s.nombre AS semestre,
    s.orden
FROM estudiante e
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id
JOIN semestre s ON s.id = c.semestre_id
WHERE s.orden = (
    SELECT max(orden) FROM caracterizacion c2
    JOIN semestre s2 ON s2.id = c2.semestre_id
    WHERE c2.estudiante_id=c.estudiante_id
)
```

En el fondo ejecutas una subconsulta por cada fila. Ineficiente pero obtienes las tres filas para tres estudiantes

## El camino tradicional

Puedes ejecutar una subconsulta a priori para saber de antemano la tupla estudiante-semestre que cumple tu condición:

```
WITH maximo_semestre AS (
  SELECT c.estudiante_id,max(s.orden) AS orden
FROM caracterizacion c
JOIN semestre s ON s.id = c.semestre_id
GROUP BY estudiante_id
)
SELECT
    e.nombre,
    c.id,
    s.nombre AS semestre,
    s.orden
FROM estudiante e
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id
JOIN semestre s ON s.id=c.semestre_id
JOIN maximo_semestre ms ON ms.estudiante_id=e.id AND ms.orden=s.orden
```

(el uso de WITH es sólo para no hacer el JOIN con la subconsulta que se ve más desordenado). De nuevo, obtienes tres filas.

## Usando window functions

El uso de window functions te permite saber agregados locales sobre un segmento de la query. En este caso no se le saca provechopero cumple el propósito

```
WITH window_query AS (
    SELECT
    e.nombre,
    c.id,
    s.nombre AS semestre,
    s.orden,
    max(s.orden) OVER (partition BY e.nombre) max_orden
FROM estudiante e
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id
JOIN semestre s ON s.id=c.semestre_id
)
SELECT nombre,
       id,
       semestre,
       orden 
FROM window_query
WHERE orden = max_orden
```

## La manera elegante

Puedes usar [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-select.html) combinando con ORDER BY para obtener todos los nombres distintos que aparecerían en tu primera consulta. Sólo obtendrás 3 registros por lo que tendrás que jugar con los ORDER BY de los campos secundarios para obtener las filas que quieres

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.nombre)
    e.nombre,
    c.id,
    s.nombre AS semestre,
    s.orden
FROM estudiante e
JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id
JOIN semestre s ON s.id=c.semestre_id
ORDER BY e.nombre, s.orden DESC
```

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, gracias