# Convertir RawQuerySet a QuerySet en DJango

Tags: django, django-models, sql

Tengo el siguiente Código:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from estudiante.models import Estudiante
from caracterizacion.models import Tipo, Caracterizacion
from .filters import EstudianteFilter

# Create your views here.

def principal(request):
    query = '''SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.id) e.id, e.nombre, e.apellido, e.estado, e.documento, c.nivelado, s.nombre AS semestre, t.nombre AS tipo 
                FROM estudiante e 
                    JOIN caracterizacion c ON c.estudiante_id = e.id 
                    JOIN semestre s ON s.id=c.semestre_id 
                    JOIN tipo t ON t.id=c.tipo_id 
                    ORDER BY e.id, s.orden DESC'''
    estudiantes = Estudiante.objects.raw(query)

    estudiantes_filter = EstudianteFilter(request.GET, queryset=estudiantes)
    print(estudiantes_filter)


    contexto = {

        'estudiantes': estudiantes,
        'filter': estudiantes_filter,
    }
    return render(request, 'reporte/principal.html', contexto)
```

En el tengo un query el cual aplico para el raw pero al intentar usar el raw en el django filter me genera error `'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'` esto porque django filter solo acepta QuerySet, entonces necesito convertir mi RawQuerySet a un QuerySet.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Deberías eliminar la pregunta anterior, que es básicamente la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces una qs en Django, puedes acceder a campos de modelos relacionados utilizando el doble subrayado, o `__`. Por ejemplo, si tienes el modelo `Estudiante` relacionado con la `Caracterización`, supongo que a través del campo `caracterizacion` o similar, puedes acceder a los campos de la caracterización utilizando esta notación, por ejemplo así: `caracterizacion__nivelado`.

Por supuesto sólo te sacará los directamente relacionados, con lo que te haría un `JOIN` *automágicamente*.

Tu consulta, si lo he entendido bien, debería ser parecida a esta:

```
Estudiante.objects.all().values('nombre', 'apellido', 'estado', 'documento'..., 'caracterizacion__nivelado', 'caracterizacion__semestre__nombre', ...)
```

Comment: Perfecto pero como hago para el `order by` ya que un estudiante puede tener multiples caracterizacion que a su vez estan asociadas a un semestre

Comment: Tendría que ver cómo se comporta el `distinct` teniendo en cuenta que pudieran haber varios semestres por estudiante.
Si tuviera que hacerlo yo, con ese diseño de bd, empezaría por ver qué resultado me sale haciendo el `order_by('pk', 'caracterizacion__semestre__order')`, pero me suena que el diseño de bd es el que te está dando problemas conceptuales.
Si tuvieras diferentes semestres por estudiante, ¿Qué semestre utilizarías para ordenar? <-- esta pregunta es para ver si realmente estoy entendiendo la cuestión.

Comment: Hola daniel, para ordenar uso el semestre con el mayor orden, te dejo el enlace a la pregunta donde expongo mi base de datos y donde me ayudaron con la consulta SQL.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215228/consulta-sql-filtro-avanzado-con-postgres

Comment: Prueba con esto: `Estudiante.objects.filter().values(...., 'caracterizacion__semestre__order').order_by('pk', 'caracterizacion__semestre__order').distinct('pk')`. Debería funcionarte con Django superior a 1.4. De todas formas me parece una query muy poco legible (sacada de la raw que te proponen, que me parece igual de compleja). Yo preferiría hacerlo en un par de consultas o tres y que fuera más legible.